# is there a deep learning model that handle 47800+ classes for classification?

Tags: python, deep-learning, machine-learning-model

I am trying to build a text classifier with 47893 classes and 1.3 billion (1,302,687,947) data samples.
What would be the best classifier to build with such kind of data? Each data label will contain industry, department, specialization, normalized role information and data have title and skills information. I have tried to build a classifier with a small amount of data and I can see the data has enough distinct information to differentiate the class information. Size of the data is 4.56 GB.

```
__label_0043-0010-1002-1005 senior_data_scientist_python,_r,_machine_learning,...
<---label information-----> <---------------data-------------------------------->
```

Previously I have trained models for around 20 classes with fasttext, but training model with fasttext is not possible and fasttext can run only on a CPU machines. It shows around 10789h to complete training. I know deep learning models on GPU work fine, but which model would be good for such a scenario?

Any suggestion is appreciated and I can add any additional information required.

Answer (score 9):

Any text-generating neural network nowadays generates tokens in a discrete space of approximately that size (30k-50k), which is analogous to a classifier of that number of classes.

With a normal Transformer encoder (e.g. BERT) with a classification head (i.e. linear projection + softmax), you should be able to handle that in terms of model capacity, without needing high-end GPUs. A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bert+text+classification+huggingface) will give you multiple tutorials on how to achieve this. If you have hardware limitations, I suggest you read the article [*Cramming: Training a Language Model on a Single GPU in One Day*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.14034).

For even larger output spaces, there are other options like sampled softmax or hierarchical softmax. [This answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23833/14675) provides more details and some pointers about that.

One aspect that you should take into account is data sparsity. Your training data should cover profusely the label space. Otherwise, your model will not perform well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *discrete space*? Why is this important? I know what an embedding space is. In particular, in some sense, a discrete topology isolates a point from another, but how are synonyms "isolated" in the resulting space? I assumed that embeddings live in a continuous space, and I acknowledge that I am not an expert. I would love to know more.

Comment: I mean "discrete representation space", meaning that the output of the model is chosen among a discrete set of options. In the case of classification, the model chooses among N different labels. In text generation models, the model chooses among the N different possible tokens of the vocabulary.

Comment: So, the embedding space (produced by the encoder) is continuous, but then there is a decision-making process based on a discretization step? In a way, the embedding (vector) is compared with the vector representation of each word/token to assign/predict for the classification/generation task? Thanks for your reply, and please keep me posted.

Comment: Yes, something like that. The embedding space produced by the encoder is compared with the output token vectors (with a linear projection) and the result is converted into a categorical probability distribution (with softmax), which is used to decide the final output (e.g. by getting the element with highest probability).

Answer (score 5):

I am unaware of deep learning architectures for your setting, but I want to share some knowledge.

*Extreme classification* is a very demanding task.$^\dagger$

There are many large-scale open-source implementations for such a task. Google's [ScaNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann) (Scalable Nearest Neighbors) is one of them, which implements this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/guo20h/guo20h.pdf). You can check their [example](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/scann/docs/example.ipynb) on the [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) dataset.

Spotify also has one called [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) (Approximate Nearest Neighbors Oh Yeah). I reference it because they have [benchmarked](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) their approach against others (including ScaNN).

---

<sub><sup>$^\dagger$ I point it out to highlight the keywords for your problem to investigate further if you want.</sup></sub>